The image $\ln([0,\infty))$
Consider the function $f(x)=\ln(x)$. I want to determine $f\big([0,\infty)\big)$ and  I hesitate between saying that it is $f\big([0,\infty)\big)=\emptyset$ because $f$ is not defined at $x=0$ and saying that $f\big([0,\infty)\big)=\mathbb R$ ignoring the fact that $f$ is not defined at $x=0$.

If you had to assign $\ln 0$ a value based on its graph, $-\infty$ would be a natural choice, so I think it would be appropriate to say the image could be written as $\mathbb{R} \cup {-\infty}$. Though I'm not sure offhand how the statement "$\ln 0 = -\infty$" may be viewed in complex analysis, due to some of the intricacies therein (e.g. with multivalued functions).

can I write $f(0)=\emptyset$ and so $f([0,\infty))=f(0)\cup f((0,\infty))=\emptyset \cup \mathbb R=\mathbb R$

If $f(0)$ is not defined then you should not be asked for it. It is hard to judge if this is a typo or something else. Whatever you decide to write, you should justify it (ie explain why it makes sense and based  on what assumption/s)

The question is to find $f([0,\infty))$ what should be my answer?

You should answer that 1) the question as it is makes no sense (explain why) 2) Either replace $[0,\infty)$ by $(0,\infty)$ or define $f(0):=-\infty$ 3) Answer this new question.

$\emptyset \notin \mathbb{R}$, despite being a subset of the reals:  $\emptyset \subset \mathbb{R}$: I think it's reasonable to map a thing to the emptyset but then we have that functions domain is the reals union with the set containing the emptyset. And then we'll have to conclude that in this case the $f(0)=\emptyset$ acts like $-\infty$. We've just introduced a new symbol and not really a helpful one.

Maybe to drive the thought home. Every positive number has been mapped to a real number and zero was mapped to a set.

$f([0,\infty))=\mathbb{R}$ reflects the range of $\ln (x)$ ignoring the fact that $x=0$ is not in the domain of the function.
Graphically, it would be logical that $\ln (0) = -\infty $.
It would be correct that $f((0,\infty)) = \mathbb{R}$ as  it excludes $0$.
You shouldn't really write out a definition for $\ln (0)$ as it goes against the definitions of logarithms. Write out the limit of $\ln (x)$ as x approaches 0 instead, if it is of any use.
